# OpenSuse Tumbleweed - Wifi Not Working

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, opensuse, sony-vaio

I'm using opensuse Tumbleweed on a sony Vaio Fit, at some point I had wifi working properly, after a reinstallation process I could no longer enable the wifi, the output for the rfkill command list:

0: sony-wifi: Wireless LAN
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
1: sony-bluetooth: Bluetooth
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
2: hci0: Bluetooth
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no

Can anyone help ???

Comment: Can you first describe the actual problem with trying to enable WiFi?

Comment: My network manager don't show de connections wifi available

Answer (score 0):

if you have any ethernet cable plug it in your computer and download wicd with the one-click install process
don't forget to type`systemctl enable wicd.service && systemctl start wicd.service` to activate wicd.
then add your user to wicd group

```
sudo usermod -g wicd yourusername
```

fill in the wicd settings with your ip and dns parameters and then you will surf
enjoy!